# Методы модели, сигналы или что-то еще?

Tags: python, django

Создал приложение учета товаров. Поработал. Вот такая схема.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, verbose_name='Номер')
    sale = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Расход')


class DocumentItem(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Накладная')
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Товар')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Количество')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.document.sale:
            self.product.stock -= self.quantity
        else:
            self.product.stock += self.quantity
        self.product.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Наименование')
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='На складе')

@receiver(post_delete, sender=DocumentItem)
def correct_stock_after_delete(sender, **kwargs):
    doc_item = kwargs.get('instance')
    if doc_item.document.sale:
        doc_item.product.stock += doc_item.quantity
    else:
        doc_item.product.stock -= doc_item.quantity
    doc_item.product.save()
```

Управление осуществляю через админ панель. При сохранении экземпляра DocumentItem, то есть при сохранении накладной Document, в зависимости от флага sale (приходная или расходная накладная), товар на складе либо увеличивается, либо уменьшается на quantity. При удалении экземпляра DocumentItem, то есть при удалении накладной Document, вызывается сигнал post_delete, который корректирует количество товара на складе. Вопрос такой. Сейчас, чтобы скорректировать количество товара в накладной (введено неверное число) нужно удалить эту строку из накладной и забить заново. Как лучше поступить, чтобы можно было корректировать количество в самой накладной?

Comment: При сохранении `DocumentItem` нужно сравнивать старое и новое значение и менять `product.stock` на _разницу_. Сейчас у вас код работает только для случая создания (т.е. предполагает, что предыдущее значение было 0). Либо нужно читать значение из БД, или запоминать при загрузке из БД одним из способов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361057/django-comparing-old-and-new-field-value-before-saving

Comment: Спасибо, я предполагал, что так , но никак не могу получить старое значение. (не знаю как это сделать). Через print пробовал выводить значения quantity, но выдает все время новое.  Пытался через сигнал pre_save.  В методе save() DocumentItem нужно получить этот экземпляр DocumentItem.objects.get(), в нем будет старое значение, а self.quantity новое? Верно?

Comment: Да, верно, но это дополнительный запрос в БД. Лучше, конечно, делать, как я писал выше.

Comment: Роман, может подскажете еще момент? Сделал через запрос в БД, работает, все корректно теперь, спасибо  В накладной могут быть повторяющиеся продукты. Как сделать так, чтобы либо при сохранении накладной в админке вылезало предупреждение, либо чтобы повторяющиеся позиции суммировались? Любой вариант устроил бы.

Comment: Это лучше описать отдельным вопросом. Такая сжатая формулировка допускает много трактовок - я не уверен, что понимаю. И обсуждать в комментариях неописанные детали вопроса - так себе занятие.